# Using find() method with relations filtering cause data missing in TypeOrm

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've been using `TypeOrm` within `Nest.js` to query `MYSQL` DB.
I try to fetch the entity along with its relation while filtering on that relation, but the result is not right as describe below.

**Query**

```
const products =
  await this.productRepository.find({
    where: {
      productCategories: { slug: In(['drinks']) },
    },
    relations: ['productCategories']
});
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  "id": 435,
  "name": "Cola",
  ...
  // Should have 2 Categories
  "productCategories": [
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "Drinks",
      "slug": "drinks",
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Cocktail Mixter",
      "slug": "cocktail-mixter",
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

**Actual Result**

```
{
  "id": 435,
  "name": "Cola",
  ...
  // Show only the one present in where clause
  "productCategories": [
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "Drinks",
      "slug": "drinks",
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

For more information, This is how relation of this 2 entities is config.

**Product Entity**

```
@Entity('product')
 export class ProductEntity {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(() => ProductCategoryEntity)
   @JoinTable({
     name: 'products_and_categories',
   })
   productCategories: ProductCategoryEntity[];
   ...
}
```

**Product Category Entity**

```
@Entity('product_category')
export class ProductCategoryEntity {
 ...
 @ManyToMany(() => ProductEntity)
 @JoinTable({
   name: 'products_and_categories',
 })
 products: ProductEntity[];
 ...
}
```